# Using Javascript to send SSH commands in a browser

Tags: javascript, ssh

My goal is to have a gateway that sends SSH commands to a remote server from a webpage. There are a few browser based extensions, but I wasn't able to find any that were exposed via Javascript. Is there a way to accomplish this client-side without a proxy server in between?

I really don't even need async communications, I really just need a "fire and forget" bucket for SSH calls triggered from a webpage, hopefully without introducing another service somewhere.

Comment: JS only has ajax, and ajax only reliably works on the http(s) protocol...

Comment: I ended up introducing a service in the form of a PHP page. The browser makes jsonp calls, the PHP script does the SSH login and commands. I've yet to find a browser-based solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out [Ajaxterm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/) which is a web based terminal.

also check [Orbited](http://labs.gameclosure.com/orbited2/) which is provides a JavaScript TCP socket API for real-time browser applications.

I hope that help you.